# Database opened throughout application lifetime

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a singleton class which handles all my database access. On each query I open the database and when query is done I close the database. This creates a lot of overhead in my opinion since my SQLiteOpenHelper can keep the database connection open for me. My question is: what are the implications if I always keep the database open?

Comment: just none most of the developers prefer to open once app start and close when it finishes

Comment: why don't you use ContentProvider ... AFAIK one instance of CP is created for instance of App (so it's an one instance until app will get killed by OS even if you're using multiple Activites and/or Services and/or Recivers)

Comment: @ingsaurabh Don't i risk leaking stuff since I am not closing the database properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756601/when-close-the-bbdd-and-when-close-the-cursor/8758775#8758775) I've tried to answer to a similar question. I think that there is huge overhead when you open and close database for all request. So maybe, as it is proposed in the comment you should open your database during the start of your application and close it when an application is destroyed. As for me I usually open database in the onResume method of the activity and I don't know if it is the right way.